# Why is DataRow["columnValue"] null in RowDataBound callback for Asp.Net GridView

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, gridview, datatable, aspxgridview

**Update**

In editing the question I have spotted my own mistake (invalid cast to a `string`.)

Many thanks to all, all suggestions most helpful.

**Original Question**

I have an `.aspx` page with a `GridView`, databound to an `ObjectDataSource` which is filled with a `DataSet` containing a `DataTable`.

When handling the `RowDataBound` callback on the `GridView` however, I am unable to reference columns in the underlying dataset by column name, they just return an object of type `DBNull`. So:

```
    protected void accountsGV_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            // One way:
            // This works, but uses a hard coded column index which
            // I want to replace.
            if (e.Row.Cells[11].Text != "&nbsp;")
            {
                // Apply certain styles to the row depending on
                // the contents of the cell.
            }


            // Another way. This doesn't work - "date" is always DBNull.
            DataRow row = (e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView).Row;
            DateTime date;

            if(!Convert.IsDBNull(row["date"]))
            {
                date = (DateTime)row["date"]);

                if (date < SomeConstantDate)
                {
                    // Apply certain styles to the row depending on
                    // the contents of the cell.
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So specifically:

- `row["date"]` returns an object of type `DBNull`.
- `row[11]` returns a `DateTime`.
- `row.Table.Columns["date"]` returns a valid `DataColumn`
- `row[row.Table.Columns["date"]]` returns an object of type `DBNull`.

Can anyone suggest why this might be happening?

**Setup**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GV" runat="server" DataSourceID="ODS"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    ... snip ...
    onrowdatabound="GV_RowDataBound" >
    <Columns> ... </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>


 <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ODS" runat="server" 
    SelectMethod="getData"
    ... snip ...
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Comment: Have you checked that the columns NAME is date and not just the fieldname?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a few things to consider.

1. `e.Row.Cells` is referring to the formatted output, not the object itself.
2. null values are rendered as non-blanking white space hence `&nbsp;`
3. column names are case sensative. "Date" != "date"
4. the column name implies the type of the value is a DateTime object, not a string, so softly casting from a DateTime to string will return null, not the string value of the DateTime object.

instead try this

```
var data = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
var date = data["Date"];
if(date != null and date.ToString() == "...")
{
   do something based on the value of date.
}
```

Comment: 1. Understood, this was existing code I need to modify. 2. I suspected this was the case. 3. I also suspected this, but the case is correct (as demonstrated by the success of `row.Table.Columns["date"]`. 4. I've corrected this (as it is indeed a `DateTime` underneath. Same problem (question updated).

Comment: what about the sql statement and databas schema, does the database allow null values? at this point the UI doesn't present any problems.